# Android Keyboard Input Method to show numbers 0-9 above standard alpha

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When entering a `username` or `password` on some sites in chrome, my google keyboard pops up with the standard alphabet portion but also with the numbers (0-9) above it (depending on the site). I've looked through the keyboard input methods and it doesn't seem that this is an option.

How would I accomplish this when entering text in an edittext?

Comment: FWIW, just because one input method editor does this, does not mean that all such input method editors do this.

Comment: Sounds like you should do some experimentation with the [android:inputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)